# Getting java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium

```
public  class TestScenario1 {

    @Test (dataProvider = "test")
    public void execute(String TestCol1,String TestCol2, String TestCol3,String TestCol4) throws Exception {            
        homePage hp = new homePage();
        hp.perform(TestCol1, TestCol2, TestCol3, TestCol4); 
    }

    @DataProvider(name= "test")
    public Object[][] testcase(ITestContext context) {
        String filepath = executionBase.CONFIG.getProperty("filepath");
        // String filepath = "D://workspace//Project//data//testData.xlsx";
        String sheetname = "Suite";
        return executionBase.getTestData(filepath, sheetname);
    } 
}
```

If I execute above code it gives me following error: 
*SKIPPED: execute
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:162)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:430)*

But if I comment this line 
String filepath =executionBase.CONFIG.getProperty("filepath");
and execute following instead,
String filepath = "D://workspace//Project//data//testData.xlsx";
it works fine

executionBase.class referred constructor code looks like,

```
public executionBase() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    CONFIG = new Properties();
    FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "//config//config.properties");
    CONFIG.load(ip);
}
```

config.properties file entry goes like this,
filepath=D:\workspace\Project\data\testData.xlsx

**Function of executionBase.class works fine for other path variables provided in config.properties, but not sure why I am getting Null value for same under 
@DataProvider(name= "test") annotation**

Comment: Can you post your DataproviderClass?

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 its a inbuild annotation of testng

Comment: The name of the class is.  Please post the class file.  Remember [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :-)

Comment: http://testng.org/javadocs/index.html its a annotation

Answer (score 0):

`Properties.load()` will escape back slashes, Try using double backslashes in the config file, or changing to forward slash:

```
filepath=D:/workspace/Project/data/testData.xlsx
```

You can also try:

```
String content = IOUtils.toString(ip, Charset.defaultCharset());
content = content.replaceAll("\\","\\\\");
CONFIG.load(content);
```

Edit: From what I can see, seems like your executionBase isn't initialized when you run your TestScenario class. Check how is executionBase() is called, and verify its called before calling it in DataProvider.

Comment: I am using double slash only in config file, also as you suggested I have tried by replacing same with forwards slashes, but still the same results. Tried running the suggested code, but load only allows Input Stream & Reader as input

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem, Open you test data sheet and press "CTRL+END", if its not the cell(lastrow,lastcolumn), then manually right click on that row or column and DELETE it. Save the file and run it, worked for me !